# How to count unique data in php mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, counter

i have some data like this..

[image]

and i want to make a table that count every unique row like this..

```
Ruang   | Tipe_Px   | Count1 | Count2
Anggrek |ASKES PNS  |4       |3
Anggrek |JAMKESMAS  |1       |2
Dahlia  |TNI        |2       |1
Dahlia  |ASKES      |5       |1
Dahlia  |ASKES BLUE |1       |0
```

to make final table like this..

```
Ruang   | Px
        |ASKES         |TNI
        |Count1|Count2 |Count1|Count2

Anggrek |0     |0      |0     |0
Dahlia  |5     |1      |2     |1
```

this my work..

```
SELECT `Ruang`,`Tipe_Px` , `JK` , COUNT(`JK`) FROM `mockup` GROUP BY `Ruang`,`Tipe_Px`,`JK`
```

and the result will be...

[image]

or maybe you have better suggestion over my case...

i try to make "if" in php.. and i think it take so many "if" to get every unique count value...
maybe you have some simple solution...
thanks... :)

Comment: Please try building query yourself. And `Hint:` use groupby

Comment: what did you try till now.?

Comment: i just update my work...  you can see it...  @jQuery.PHP.Magento.com  :)

Comment: just need to use conditional aggregation. i have no idea why you accepted the answer you did when it doesn't really help.

Comment: wow..  i just see your answer @pala_ thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation (this requires knowing in advance the possible values for `JK`.

```
select Ruang, Tipe_px, count(case when jk = 1 then 1 end) count1, count(case when jk = 2 then 1 end) count2
  from <your table>
  group by Ruang, Tipe_px
```

Comment: yes values of JK is just two.. 1 or 2...  thats great.. thanks..  :)